# Resetting color to null using echo prints an i character at the end, how to avoid it?

Tags: bash, colors, echo

I'm working on an installation script that should perform various tasks and exit with an error code on the first failure.

When performing a task it prints to the standard output a comment string and whether the task succedes or not it prints "OK" or "FAIL" accordingly.

I wish to color OK green and FAIL red so i have used ansi/vt100 color codes, but when i reset the color back to null for some reason i found that an 'ì' character is appended to the text.

Here is a simplified version of the script i use:

```
#!/bin/sh

GREEN='\033[0;32m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'

task() {
        echo -n "$1..."
        if $2 >> $LOG 2>&1; then
                echo "${GREEN}OK${NC}"
        else
                echo "${RED}FAIL${NC}"
        fi
}

LOG=./task.log
echo "Starting long task executor" > $LOG

if ! task "Performing a long task" "sleep 3"; then
        exit 1
fi

echo "Bye"
```

and here is the output:

```
Performing a long task...OKì 
Bye
```

Why i have that 'ì' at the end of the OK?

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of your `TERM` environment variable? (`echo $TERM`)

Comment: the value is xterm-256color, is it useful?